# phonebook application, how to add for user an unlimited amount of phone numbers?

Tags: django

I'm new in django. Trying to create a simple phone book web application. When I'm creating a contact I need to add to that user an unlimited amount of phone numbers with different types (cell phone, home phone, work phone,  etc.) For example: for user1 I need to add 5 numbers, for user2 add 10 numbers. How should I do this?

Comment: Use a foreign key to a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use [user model from django contrib auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) then you can just create new model for phonebook

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
  user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 15, blank=True)
  home_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 15, blank=True)
  work_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 15, blank=True)
```

else, if you have your own user model just change `User` on `ForeignKey()` with your Model name